# imextendedmin and imimposemin functions in python for watershed seeds from distance transform

Tags: python, image, matlab, opencv

In matlab, I can use these functions from the image processing toolbox in order to "clean" a distance transform and locate the seeds for watershed algorithm. The tutorials I found for python include thresholding the distance transform to get the seeds, which doesnt work well in my case because not all my features are the same size, and the intensity of the distance transform depends on absolute distance from the background.

I have [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OpjY.png) an example of what those functions accomplish in matlab, where the white regions are the seeds. Is there a way I can achieve this in python, either with existing functions or coding it on my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab documentation credits *Soille, P. Morphological Image Analysis: Principles and Applications. Springer-Verlag, 1999* for most of it's image morphology stuff. It's a really good read when trying to translate these functions.

## imextendedmax():

`imextendedmin()` gets the regional minima of the H-minima transform, where the H-minima transform is just morphological reconstruction by erosion of the image using (image + H) as the marker. Scikit-image has all the morphology tools needed to do this:

```
import skimage.morphology as morph

def extendedmin(img, H):
    mask = img.copy() 
    marker = mask + h  
    hmin =  morph.reconstruction(marker, mask, method='erosion')
    return morph.local_minima(hmin)
```

Matlab result:
[`imextendedmin()` on "glass.png"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoR40.png)
This function's result:
[python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxyAW.png)

## imimposemin()

`imimposemin()` does minima imposition on a image using a binary map with 1s where you want to impose the minima. The function I detail below works for an image composed of integers ranging from 0 to infinity. To do this with morphology, we need to turn the binary map into a marker with 0 at the minima and the maximum possible image value elsewhere. Next, we create a mask by taking the element-wise minimum of the (image+1) and the marker (image + 1 allows you to impose minima where the image is already at 0). The final result is given by reconstruction by erosion of the mask from the marker.

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.morphology as morph

def imposemin(img, minima):
    marker = np.full(img.shape, np.inf)
    marker[minima == 1] = 0
    mask = np.minimum((img + 1), marker)
    return morph.reconstruction(marker, mask, method='erosion')
```

Matlab result:
[`imimposemin()` on "glass.png" (left image has the marker superimposed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwWPY.png)
This function's result:
[python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKKrS.png)